# WebAudio oscillator "click"

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Whenever I try a simple oscillator (check [this example](http://webaudioapi.com/samples/oscillator/). It is not mine, but it shows the same problem) I hear a "click" when it starts and when it ends.

How can I bypass this issue?

Comment: Note: This question (and its answers) is plagiarised at `devdreamz DOT com/question/583742-webaudio-oscillator-click`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To stop the click, you need to ramp the oscillator up smoothly instead of instantaneously starting it.  Something like the following:

```
var osc = context.createOscillator();
var gain = context.createGain();
osc.connect(gain);
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime);
gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, context.currentTime + <some small time>);

osc.start();
...
// To stop the oscillator, ramp the gain down.
gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, endTime - <small time>);
osc.stop(endTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add a gain, you can make the oscillation stop after a fixed number of periods:

```js
const ac = new AudioContext
const osc = ac.createOscillator()

const freq = 220
const start = 2 + ac.currentTime
const length = Math.random() * 2
const period = length * freq
const roundedPeriod = Math.round(period)
const correctedLength = roundedPeriod / freq
const end = start + correctedLength

osc.connect(ac.destination)
osc.frequency.value = freq
osc.start(start)
osc.stop(end)
```

A more robust example is here:
https://codepen.io/yukulele/pen/QWMZGOZ